# How to check for a presence of at least one parameter using express-validator

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I'm using **express** and **express-validator** in my Nodejs app. I want to check for the presence of at least one of incoming parameters. Its sort of either or combination.

Lets say my service accepts 2 parameters. I want to be sure **at least one of them** is provided by the client.

The below code would work for just one. But I have no idea how to make it either or.

```
req.checkBody('param1', 'Mandatory field param1 not populated').notEmpty();
```

Answer (score 12):

Say you want to update a model that has `id`, `status`, and `content`... like a social media post, for example. Your controller may support updating the `status` of the model or its `content`. So, you could do something like the following:

```
export const updateModelValidation = [
    param('id').exists().isNumeric(), // <-- required model identifier
    oneOf( // <-- one of the following must exist
        [
          body('status').exists().isString(),
          body('content').exists().isString(),
        ],
    ),
];
```

Comment: In order for the `oneOf` to work you need to require it from the `express-validator` package

Answer (score 1):

You could use multiple validation chains and use the oneOf function to validate against at least 1 validation chain.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator#oneofvalidationchains-message